# Webpack - Optimizing the compile time(with hot reloading)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hot-middleware

We are using `webpack-hot-middleware` for our dev env.

The problem is that the compile has gotten up to 30secs with the code growth.

I am trying to implement the suggestions at: https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html.

So about the `DYNAMIC LINKED LIBRARY` I found a great tutorial: http://engineering.invisionapp.com/post/optimizing-webpack/

The problem is that all the tutorials about the `DllPlugin` are regarding a build and not with hot reloading.

Does anyone know how to implement this with the `webpack-hot-middleware` or any other hot-reloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end came out that the problem was that i was using `devTool:source-map` and I should have used `source-map-eval` which uses caching, this reduced the compile time to 2-3 seconds!

So the dynamic DLL solutions is only applicable for build and is not needed for hot-reloading which re-compiles the delta's pretty fast